# Vb project trying to get rid of vb6 references

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

I have a project that VS opens as a VB project. The project runs fine but I have been asked to remove all VB6 references, such as these:

[image]

Since it's an old project I think that it was written to VB6 then it was converted to VB.NET but some lines didn't adapt. How should I deal with it?

Comment: Looks like a time bomb just waiting for somebody to light the High DPI fuse.

Comment: I believe that .Net only works with pixels. I would step through the code and note what the TwipsToPixels function returns in each case and assign those values directly.

Comment: A twip is an old typographical unit of measurement roughly equivalent to 1/20 of a point, or 1440 of an inch. The per pixel conversion depends on the screen resolution, but 15 twips per pixel is common. Like Jerry M said, just set the values. So .Left = VB6.TwipsToPixelsX(60) becomes .Left = 4.

Comment: You should know, this is not a REAL VB6 reference: It is a reference to a .NET library build by M$ for an easy (VB6 style) way to bring old applications to VB.NET. Therefore they can be used as long .NET will exist.